# Internal Server Error in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying localhost:8000 url and then html appended to it.
and error 500 happen.

I used this [Setup](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JeffreyWay/Vagrant-Setup/master/install.sh)
and apache version 2.4.16
with this htaccess setting :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: make sure your storage directory has 777 permissions

Comment: could you trace ur apache log?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal This is last line of it. `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: has ur laravel log folder has enough permission ?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal I'm using LA 5.1 execute `chmod -R o+w storage`